# Right to Left Match Count Non-Blank Cells

Tags: count, excel-formula, match, right-to-left

How do I modify this formula:

```
=MATCH(1,--(AA1:AH1=""),0)-1
```

to count from right to left?  I want to count the number of non-blank cells until a blank cell, but I need to do it starting from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

The array formula (confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>)

```
=MAX(IF(LEN(AA1:AH1)<>0,COLUMN(AA1:AH1)))
```

should give you the index of the column containing the last non-blank cell, even in a row with multiple intercalated blank cells.

The array formula (confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>)

```
=MAX(IF(LEN(AA1:AH1)=0,COLUMN(AA1:AH1)))
```

should give you the index of the column containing the last blank cell, even in a row with multiple intercalated blank cells.

You could then use this values to calculate your desired results.

i.e.:
[image: example table to this topic attempt]

To put it all together:

```
=MAX(IF(LEN(AA1:AH1)<>0,COLUMN(AA1:AH1))) - MAX(IF(LEN(AA1:AH1)=0,COLUMN(AA1:AH1)))
```

should give you your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with match() function, but you can do it otherwise with following with Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
=8-MAX(IF(AA1:AG1="",COLUMN(AA1:AG1)-26))
```

Thank You,